# Logout from Kubeflow application with Auth0 causing infinite loop

Tags: auth0, kubeflow

I am trying to setup authentication to Kubeflow with Auth0, following this manual: [Authentication using OIDC](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/aws/authentication-oidc/) (with the difference, I setup google account instead of github as a IdP)

Now I am able to login with my Google account to kubeflow via auth0 (my email whitelisted in auth0 rule which allowing connection to the kubeflow application).

When I click to logout link in kubeflow it is running into an infinite loop. Looks like it redirecting to the same kubeflow logout URL. How can I setup redirect properly?

Comment: Created an issues in the kubeflow repository https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/issues/5704